# Can Availability Group be configured in a below structure?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, distributed-availability-groups

I have Production and DR clusters as depicted on a picture below.

My question is whether there is a way to configure Availability Group from datacenter1 to datacenter2?

1. I tried to configure regular AG from Production to DR but it seems like it will not be possible
   because all 4 nodes needs to be under the same WSFC.
2. Thought about creating distributed AG, but as I understand  distributed AG goes on a "top" of
   regular AG.

So am I correct to assume that with this structure I will no be able to implement Availability Group?

[image]

Error if I try to create AG using wizard:

[image]

Comment: `DR Server 1` and `DR Server 2` are part of the same WSFC.
But `ProdServer1` and `Prod Server 2` belong to different WSFC.

Comment: Also, there is FCI between `DR Server 1` and `DR Server 2`. Same with Production servers, they have FCI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

You describe that the servers are already configured in separate WSFCs, so you will either need to destroy one of the clusters (presumably the DR cluster), and reconfigure into a single WSFC, or you will need to configure the DR FCI to be a single-instance AG, so that you can then configure the Distributed AG to run atop the Prod & DR AGs.

#### The long answer

You can configure your Availability Group(AG) through either method you describe. Whether it is right for you to configure a single AG that spans both data centers, or to use a Distributed AG is a more complicated question--but both are possible.

1. A single Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC) and a single AG, which span all 4 servers in 2 data centers.

   - `ProdServer1`, `ProdServer2`, `DRServer1`, `DRServer2` are all part of THE SAME WSFC
   - `DRServer1` & `DRServer2` are part of an FCI, `DR\Instance`
   - `ProdServer1` & `ProdServer2` have standalone instances
   - An AG is configured to span `ProdServer1`, `ProdServer2`, and `DR\Instance`
   - The AG will be a Multi-Subnet AG, and there will be configuration details to consider on client and/or server side. I've written about some of those considerations [here](https://am2.co/2020/10/multi-subnet-registerallprovidersip-1/) & [here](https://am2.co/2020/10/multi-subnet-registerallprovidersip-2/)

2. A distributed AG that spans two data centers

   - `ProdServer1`, `ProdServer2` are part of one WSFC
   - `ProdServer1` & `ProdServer2` have standalone instances
   - An AG (`Prod_AG`) is configured to span `ProdServer1` & `ProdServer2`
   - `DRServer1`, `DRServer2` are all part of a different WSFC
   - `DRServer1` & `DRServer2` are part of an FCI (`DR\Instance`),

     - or reconfigured to be standalone instances, similar to the Prod Servers.
   - An AG (`DR_AG`) is configured with `DR\Instance` as the only member

     - or the reconfigured standalone instances are configured in the AG
   - A Distributed AG is configured to span `Prod_AG`, `DR_AG`

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: Just one more thing: is Availability Group is something that everyone should be using? In terms of it is the best and most reliable way to protect your data from unwanted events?

Comment: Availability Groups are not the only technology for High Availability & Disaster Recovery. However, how to select which technology is the right solution for your needs is more complicated than I'm able to respond to in comments.